# How can I make a Python package that is platform-specific?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a Python package that can only meaningfully run on Linux. I've seen in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data) that there is a `platforms` key in the `setup.py` metadata, but as far as I can tell from poking around in the `distutils` source, this metadata isn't actually *used* for anything.

Next, I went and looked at PyObjC, a prominent OS X-only Python package. I observe that it populates the aforementioned `platforms` key in its `setup.py`. However, when I try to install PyObjC on Linux, the installation isn't prevented or blocked in any intentional way. The failure mode that ensues is pretty ungraceful: it errors out when `platform.mac_ver()` returns a value it doesn't expect. I tried manually fixing that problem, and `distutils` appeared to be going about its merry way collecting dependencies, etc. until eventually it failed looking for a platform specific file... Bottom line, `distutils` is not handling platform-specific packages in any reasonable way.

Ideally, I would expect the installation to fail with some message indicating that the package is not compatible with the current platform. I've noodled around a bit and the "best" thing I've been able to come up with involves subclassing the `install` and `develop` commands and handling a platform check manually there.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I am probably oversimplifying, but at the top of your `setup.py` couldn't you just do something like:

```
import platform
distname,version,id = platform.linux_distribution()
if not distname:
   raise Exception('Aborting installation: Requires Linux')
```

Comment: Yeah, this certainly works, and is mostly the way I've gone with it, but it's just kinda clunky. :-/